# Weird character at the end of database entry

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I am migrating an excel sheet (csv) to mysql, however when I do an insert, some fields end up with empty spaces at the end, and I cant get rid of them for some reason. So I assume there is a wierd character at the end, since not even this:

```
    UPDATE FOO set FIELD2 = TRIM(Replace(Replace(Replace(FIELD2,'\t',''),'\n',''),'\r',''));
```

Gets rid of it completely, I still have a whitespace at the end and I dont know how to get rid of it. I have over 2000 entries, so doing it manually is not an option. I am using Laravel with the revision package and it doesnt work because it thinks that those spaces at the end are changes and it creates a bunch of duplicates. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you think there are weird characters in the original csv, you could open it in a text processor capable of doing regex replaces, and then replace all non ascii characters with nothing.

Your regex would look like this:

`[^\u0000-\u007F]+`

then after removing any possible strange characters, re-import the data into the database.

Unfortunately, I don't think regex replaces are possible in sql, so you'll need to re-import.

Comment: My queries look like this:

        INSERT INTO phones VALUES ( `id`,'1Deployed','Apple - iPhone 6 - 16GB - Space Grey','','3592320628713XX','VZW','NA','','11/30/2016','4','5','11/30/2016','77%','OK','ZS','12/14/2016','Mike','229-256-8990','89148000002490813042','','','AAA','','','''','',0,null,null);

No white spaces or weird things, its when the data gets inserted that I have those problems.

Comment: @MarioLanda have you tried the mySQL function [trim](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_trim)?

Comment: Isnt that the one I mentioned above?

        UPDATE FOO set FIELD2 = TRIM(Replace(Replace(Replace(FIELD2,'\t',''),'\n',''),'\r',''));

Comment: oh, sorry, I missed it :P. Yeah, even the `Replace` functions shouldn't be needed. Can you post some example data to show what it looks like in the database? Have you tried copying the data into your clipboard and then pasting it into a site like this? http://www.babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/whatisit.html

Comment: I have a huge query , about 400 lines long full of those " INSERT INTO " commands as the one I showed you above for each company that we manage. Also that page you sent me just says that they are blank spaces, which they are not :/ . I dont know what to do anymore

Comment: Are you sure it isn't just the way you're selecting the data that's adding a space somehow? Try using `SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(some_field)` to see if the character length is what you expect it to be